# Error GlassFish 5.0.1 when start server: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/CurveDB

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, glassfish

Good morning, Stack overflow community

I am trying to build GlassFish 5.0.1 with intellij Idea, and when I run the server the localhost with port 8080 runs excellent, but the admin that by default is in 4848 throws me a blank page, on the contrary if I run the server from the GlassFish bin folder this one runs for me without problems, the problem is only when I run it from intellij idea.

This is the error that the console throws me:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/CurveDB

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/CurveDB
at sun.security.ec.SunEC.putEntries(SunEC.java:118)
at sun.security.ec.SunEC.<init>(SunEC.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:233)
at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:331)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:157)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.getSSLContext(SSLUtils.java:146)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils.postConstruct(SSLUtils.java:126)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:327)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.SecuritySniffer.setup(SecuritySniffer.java:134)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ContainerStarter.startContainer(ContainerStarter.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:997)
```

I am using jdk 1.8 to run the glassfish and these are my configurations: Configuration in intellij Idea
[configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlJJI.png)

localhost port 8080

[port 8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CCLW.png)

localhost port 4848

[port 4848 admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A90KY.png)

thank you very much for your help

Comment: I have exact same problem